# declare an object c#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have the following code:

```
object myObject = new Object()
```

I am trying to check the value of myObject when it assigned a null value.

So I use

```
if (myObject !=null)
```

....but this doesn't seem to work as it still executes the code in the if statement when the value of myObject = null

```
        if (lawyerResponsibleUserField != null
                && lawyerResponsibleUserField.Id != null)
            {
                 // this effectively assigns Convert.ToString(null)
                objLawyerResponsibileValue = Convert.ToString(workflowProperties != null 
                    ? workflowProperties.Item[lawyerResponsibleUserField.Id]
                        : null );
            }
        if (objLawyerResponsibileValue != null)
        {
            lawyerResponsibleFieldValue = (SPFieldUserValue)objLawyerResponsibileValue;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us some fuller code?

Comment: If you've assigned a new instance of `object` to `myObject` then it isn't null.

Comment: Can you post a more complete sample? i.e. The smallest complete function that will show the problem happening.

Comment: Have you seen that myObject is *actually* null in the debugger with your own eyes?  Is != overloaded for whatever type myObject is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    object myObject = null;

    if(myObject != null)
    {
     // your code
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Van -

This assignment statement -

```
object myObject = new Object();
```

...makes it not null.  =)  It would only be null if you were to write:

```
object myObject = null;
```

What's the goal here?

Answer (score 1):

Try these,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object myObject = new Object();
        if (myObject == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My Object is null");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My Object is NOT null");
        }
    }
```

Writes `My Object is NOT null`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object myObject = null;
        if (myObject == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("myObject is null");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My Object is NOT null");
        }
    }
```

Writes `My Object is null`